# md-toggle-button not toggling in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to show some toggle buttons, as the ones presents in the documentation page of angular material https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/overview . I followed the code, tryied both

```
<md-button-toggle ng-click="vm.callAlert()">Hello</md-button-toggle>
```

and

```
<mat-button-toggle ng-click="vm.callAlert()">Hello</mat-button-toggle>
```

and the function is called. The problem is that the button not stay focused. Can someone help me with that ?

Comment: take a look if you have the "close" function called somewhere in your code, or if the "toggle" function is called more than once

Comment: By the way, the documentation site you're referencing is **not for AngularJS 1.x, but for Angular 2, 4 and 5**!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **please do not use `ng-click`** in your template. Use the `(click)` event instead. For more info, visit the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax) for template syntaxes.

Secondly, note that Angular no longer uses controller syntax.

Thirdly, import `MatButtonToggleModule` from `@angular/material` in your app's module file.

Update your code to the following:

HTML code (`app.component.html`):

```html
<mat-button-toggle (click)="clickActn()">Toggle me!</mat-button-toggle>
```

Component code (`app.component.ts`):

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    clickActn() {
        console.log('clicked');
    }
}
```

- For more info about Angular, visit the [official documentation site](https://angular.io) to learn more!
- [Angular Migration Guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade)